# Installing conflicting ubuntu packages

Tags: linux, package, dependencies

Im working on installing Autospy, and I need to install the java bindings for sleuthkit.  As I am doing this, the instructions are to download the .deb file, and run this.  I do this and it is telling me I am missing certain packages in the error below.

```
sleuthkit-java : Depends: libewf2 (>= 20121209) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libvhdi1 (>= 20150110) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libvmdk1 (>= 20150516) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I run sudo apt-get install libewf2, it will then install libewf2, however it will remove libewf-dev.

When I go to install the debian package again, I get the following error.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 sleuthkit-java : Depends: libvhdi1 (>= 20150110) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libvmdk1 (>= 20150516) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libewf-dev (>= 20130416) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

My question is how do I install the java binding, if the dependencies keep uninstalling themselves when I install the other one.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please update your question https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67949401/edit to include your OS name + version .... and a link to the "sleuthkit-java" package ( which doesn't seem to match your OS.)

Comment: Build sleuthkit with java, examples https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M7Qf2ChjyIXsyUm9mZFkN36hJrBdLqnv/view?usp=sharing